# Use paste to combine letters instead or loops. R

Tags: r, loops, concatenation, paste

I'm a newbie to R, but I'm trying to make a sliding window in R.

Using loops I can it like this, but this gets very inefficient.

```
results=c(1:7)
letters=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
for(i in 1:7){
results[i]=paste(letters[i:(i+3)],collapse="")
}
```

How can I use an apply function to get the same output?

Comment: just an fyi `letters` and `LETTERS` are [built-in constants](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Constants.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this

```
sapply(1:7, function(i) {
  paste(letters[i:(i+3)], collapse = '')
})
```

Answer (score 9):

A little different to Ramnath's answer:

```
lets <- LETTERS[1:10]
substring(paste(lets,collapse=""),1:7,4:10)
#[1] "ABCD" "BCDE" "CDEF" "DEFG" "EFGH" "FGHI" "GHIJ"
```

Comment: I assume you meant `LETTERS`, not `letters`, on the first line of code.

Answer (score 4):

With the `zoo` time series package:

```
apply(rollapply(letters,4,c), 1, paste, collapse="")
[1] "ABCD" "BCDE" "CDEF" "DEFG" "EFGH" "FGHI" "GHIJ"
```

Answer (score 3):

A "roll your own" way just for fun:

```
## n letters
nl <- 10
## length of string
len <- 4
## note I use the inbuilt LETTERS
apply(matrix(LETTERS[seq_len(nl)], nl + 1, len), 1, paste, collapse = "")[seq_len(nl - len + 1)]
```

(Leaves you with a warning based on incomplete recycling, but I like the trick of using a matrix to provide the offset for rolling windows).

Comment: +1. This is very efficient, especially when the function to be rolled is vectorized over matrices. The only drawback I've found with this approach, is that there will occur an error in matrix allocation, when the vector and the window size is large, while the other approaches will just be slow.